# Wicket two links in same column

Tags: java, wicket

I want to add to all my tree nodes edit and create new child links, but I am getting error that child with id cell is already existing.

```
columns.add(new AbstractColumn<Classification, String>(Model.of("")) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void populateItem(Item<ICellPopulator<Classification>> cellItem, String componentId,
                final IModel<Classification> rowModel) {

            cellItem.add(new TreeLinkPanel(componentId, rowModel, tree));
        }
    });
    columns.add(new AbstractColumn<Classification, String>(Model.of("")) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void populateItem(Item<ICellPopulator<Classification>> cellItem, String componentId,
                final IModel<Classification> rowModel) {

            cellItem.add(new ClassificationNewLink(componentId, rowModel, tree));
        }
    });
```

For now I am doing this, but this one is ugly. I can't write header for my column. Any ideas how to put two links in same column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cell item is just a component that has its wicket id, so you cannot really add it more than once.

The simplest way is to create an panel or fragment that contains any of components you want to add (e.g. two links).

**your code example:**

```
columns.add(new AbstractColumn<Classification, String>(Model.of("")) {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void populateItem(Item<ICellPopulator<Classification>> cellItem, String componentId, final IModel<Classification> rowModel) {
        // your model
        cellItem.add(new MyCellPanel(componentId, rowModel, tree));
    }
});
```

**MyCellPanel class example:**

```
public class MyCellPanel extends Panel {

    MyCellPanel(String componentId, final IModel<Classification>rowModel, final Tree tree) {
        super(componentId, rowModel);
        add(new TreeLinkPanel("treeLink", rowModel, tree); {
        add(new ClassificationNewLink("classificationNewLink", rowModel, tree); {

    }

}
```

**MyCellPanel.html example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    <wicket:panel xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
        <div wicket:id="treeLink">tree link</div>
        <a wicket:id="classificationNewLink">classification link</a>
    </wicket:panel>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a wild guess, but what if you try to populate the column only once:

```
columns.add(new AbstractColumn<Classification, String>(Model.of("")) {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void populateItem(Item<ICellPopulator<Classification>> cellItem, String componentId,final IModel<Classification> rowModel) {
        // your model
        cellItem.add(new TreeLinkPanel("treeLinkPanelId", rowModel, tree));
        // the add link
        cellItem.add(new ClassificationNewLink("classificationNewLinkId", rowModel, tree));
    }
});
```

Comment: If I understand your code example it throws the WicketRuntimeException because you add two components with the same componentId in the same level of component hierarchy, doesn't it?